# Python Socket Error : A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and no address was supplied

Tags: python, sockets, server, ursina

I am currently creating a multiplayer game and files named `client.py` and `server.py`. The server is launching properly, multiple clients can connect, everything is working fine.

What I want now is the **server to restart once the game is finished** instead of closing and restarting manually. I tried several methods with the modules `sys` and `os` but all of them thrown with an error.
I suppose I need to close the server then launch it again. I use the module [UrsinaNetworking](https://github.com/kstzl/UrsinaNetworking) to make it easier.

I wrote the following functions in `server.py` :

```py
def GenerateServer():
    print("Hello from the server !")
    global Server
    Server = UrsinaNetworkingServer("localhost", 25565)
    global Easy
    Easy = EasyUrsinaNetworkingServer(Server)
```

```py
@Server.event
def EndGame(Client, when):
    Server.close()
    GenerateServer()
```

I needed to add the `Server.close()` in the module file `ursinanetworking.py` in the `class UrsinaNetworkingServer():`

```py
    def close(self):
        self.server.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.server.close() # Built-in Socket API function
        print ("closed")
```

And that throws into the following an error.

> Python Socket Error : A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and no address was supplied

Am I missing the point or something? Let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: Why? Why close and reopen it? What’s the point?

Comment: @user207421 to reset data in it

Comment: ‘To reset data in it’ why?

Comment: to start a new game!